# AWS Cognito based Authentication for API Gateway API'S

Tags: api, authorization

I have some set of users in cognito user pool under different groups . Example: 5 users in admin group, 20 users in supervisor group.I have created app client in cognito and enabled some Oauth2 scopes builtin and custom scopes.
Now i have API Gateway API's in which  COGNITO AUTHORIZER is enabled for auth.These apis are working fine.

**Problem faced:**
With the above method i'm able to access my apis , but how to i control API access based on the user scope.
All users in the pool has all scopes enabled. The only things which will differentiate a user is the cognito:group , in api auth setting , I'm only able to set scope, in this case all users irrespective of group has all scopes, so they are getting authenticated. How to i control the flow based on type of users?

Answer (score 0):

When you create an User group, you have an IAM role attached to it.

It will be on this that you can control access to your API by setting permission on execute api :

```
arn:aws:execute-api:{region}:{account}:{apiId}/{stage}/{method}/{ressource}
```

where all {parameter} can be wildcar * to match all.

You can find the IAM Role ARN of your user group on his description and so go in the IAM console and update this role permission

So your policy can be something like this :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:1564543246:badfg687e/*/*/petstore"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:1564543246:badfg687e/*/*/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

By example, this permission allow users part of the group attached to this IAM role to execute all method on the ressource petstore of API badfg687e and deny all other access.

Comment: This method will work for user group and users created in IAM. In my case all the users are part of cognito user pool.

Comment: @AravindC Yes I'm not talking about IAM User. Your cognito user is part of a cognito user group. And this cognito user group is attached to an IAM Role. And you control access on this IAM Role. You can find this role in your cognito user group